Kong no escucha el puerto 8000
Tengo un proyecto de microservicios en gcp. Kong es un apigateway utilizando docker.
Cuando inicio el docker y pongo a correr alguna maquina de los servicios. AL ingresar a http con la ipExterna del kong y el puerto 8000 con su respectiva ruta no carga.
Ademas, cuando realizo este comando sobre el kong curl -v http://34.72.102.27:8000/estudiantes me sale esto:

Trying 34.72.102.27:8000...
connect to 34.72.102.27 port 8000 from 10.128.0.81 port 38208 failed: Connection refused
Failed to connect to 34.72.102.27 port 8000 after 0 ms: Could not connect to server
closing connection #0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 34.72.102.27 port 8000 after 0 ms: Could not connect to server

Ayer funcionaba pero de la nada dejo de funcionar.
Gracias de antemano
intente para el kong, reiniciarlo, no puedo borrarlo porque perderia todo el avance que llevo en mi proyecto.
